# Electric Weighing Rain Gauge in Proteus

Tags: proteus

I am trying to simulate a model on Proteus where I get to measure the amount of rainfall using Adruino UNO. I have used the following components (See image)

[image]

Here is the Adruino Code,

[image]

But when I run the code, it does not give any reading. Here is the image,

[image]